Can a Power BI calculated column reflect user input?
I'm trying to let a user use a slicer to determine how important something is on a scale of 1-10, which I then want to do various other calculations on within the data table, like multiplying by values to get weighted results.
I can do this in measures using virtual tables, but when i start factoring in the various table relationships and hierarchies it gets more limited and i can't achieve what i'd like to with the report, so ideally it would need to be done at table/column level.
However, i can't get a calculated column to recognise input from a slicer. Is this possible?
For example i have my 'Weights' table with scores of 1-10, unconnected to the data table (as i've got several weights tables for different subjects, and don't want to be filtering things out of the dataset).
I was hoping to have a simple calculated column like
User_Score = Max('Weights'[Score])

However this ignores filter input. Is there any way to achieve this?

Calculated columns do not respond to slicers. You will need to use a measure to do that.
